# Statistical mechanics: Canonical Partition Function for a Polymer in a lattice

Tags: statistical-mechanics, partition-function

First time poster here so I hope I'm not missing anything.

**The question**

"Consider a simple, lattice model for a polymer. In this model, the polymer sits on a square lattice,
and at every lattice point, the polymer can do one of three things: go straight or choose between
the two directions which makes right $90^{\circ}$ angles with respect to its current direction. Each time
the polymer bends (follows a right angle, $90^{\circ}$), it pays a bending energy penalty of $\epsilon$ ; it pays nothing to continue on straight. Additionally, assume that the starting segment of the polymer is fixed somewhere on the lattice, assume the polymer consists of $N + 1$ segments, and assume that
the polymer is free to overlap itself. Calculate the canonical partition function for the system"

**What I've tried**

The partition function is defined as $Z =\sum_{i=0}^\infty \exp(-\beta \cdot E_i ) $
The different micro-states in this cases are the different paths of the polymer on the lattice.
So for one micro state, the total energy in the micro state ($E_i$) should be the number of times a $90^{\circ}$ turn is made, times the bending energy $\epsilon$.
$$
Z = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \exp(-\beta \cdot \epsilon \cdot m_i )
$$
where m is the number of times a turn is made.

I am having trouble imagining and finding the combinatorics that describe a path of the polymer along the lattice, where every turn/straight $N$ will be counted. Any hints the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since the initial segment is fixed, you can encode the geometry of the polymer in a sequence $a_1a_2\dots a_N$, where $a_k\in\{S,L,R\}$. Here, of course, $S$, $L$ and $R$ denote "straight", "left" and "right" respectively. Summing over all polymer geometries amounts to summing over all possible values for $a_1,\dots,a_N$. The energy is easily expressed in terms of the $a_i$ and the Boltzmann weight factorizes. The computation is then immediate.

Comment: So, for instance, when $N=2$ and the initial segment connects (0,0) with (1,0), the sequence L,L,S corresponds to the polymer that goes through (0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1), (-1,1) and its energy is $2\epsilon$.

Comment: @YvanVelenik  I drawed it out, and i see what you mean by the path. What I don't see is how i can express every possible path $a_i$.. We need to now the paths to know how much energy that particularpath/microstate has right?

Comment: Each sequence corresponds to one path and reciprocally (it is a bijection). You also only need the sequence to determine the energy of the path (how many L or R steps). So summing over paths is exactly the same as summing over such sequences (given that the first segment is fixed). And summing over sequences is simply $\sum_{a_1\in\{L,R,S\}}\cdots\sum_{a_N\in\{L,R,S\}}$... In the canonical ensemble, the computation is then trivial. It's only in the microcanonical ensemble that you'd need to do some (simple) combinatorics.

Comment: Maybe one last hint : the Boltzmann weight associated to the path characterized by the sequence $a_1\dots a_N$ is $\exp\bigl(-\epsilon \cdot (1_{a_1\neq S} + \cdots + 1_{a_N\neq S})\bigr) = \exp(-\epsilon\cdot 1_{a_1\neq S}\bigr) \cdots \exp(-\epsilon\cdot 1_{a_1\neq S}\bigr)$. See how to do the sum now?

Comment: @YvanVelenik Thank you for the quick response and your time. What exactly is meant when you say "So summing over paths is exactly the same as summing over such sequences (given that the first segment is fixed)."? The sequence consists over L's, R's and S's right? So from your previous example, the sum would be L + L + S ? Or what is meant by $\sum_{a_1 \in {L,S,R}}$? I'm sorry I'm not getting it already

Comment: @YvanVelenik I see what you mean now by the sum and how it factorizes. But isn't the problem still that we don't know the (number) of elements of $a_N$ that meet the restriction of not being S ?

Comment: Since everything factorizes, one just gets the product of $N$ terms of the form $\sum_{a_k\in\{L,R,S\}}\exp(-\epsilon\cdot1_{a_k\neq S}) = 2 e^{-\epsilon}+1$. Do you see how to conclude now?

Comment: I think I see where to sum comes from and how it factorizes. I will try to conclude it. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. :)